# Preencher combobox java com consulta ao mysql

Tags: mysql, combobox

estou com uma dúvida em relação a como implementar o carregamento items em uma combobox a partir de dados de uma tabela no mysql. O problema consiste em selecionar na combobox o nome de um fornecedor e então atribuir a esse objeto pagamento os atributos do fornecedor para entao imprimir uma ordem de pagamento. Mas deparei com o fato de que o combobox ao receber o valor apenas cria um índice para cada item.

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens? senão a pergunta fica dificil de responder.